# Python cgi on apache server

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I am new to python cgi programming. I have installed apache 2.2 server on linux mint and I have my html form in var/www folder which is being displayed properly. Action to the form is a cgi script that I've put in the folder /usr/lib/cgi-bin. But on submit, it says "The requested URL /usr/lib/cgi-bin/file.cgi as not found on this server." Does anyone know the fix for this?

Comment: You might like to use something like mod_wsgi to run your python app over a wsgi interface, rather than using CGI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What is the name of your Python program? Is it `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/file.cgi`?
2. What are the rights of this file? Can it be read by apache? Can it be executed?
3. Is first line with `#!/usr/bin/env python` or similar good? Make sure that this file can be run from command line (ie. shebang is good)
4. Does apache receive request with that file? Look at apache logs, especially `error.log` and `access.log` (probably in `/var/log/apache`)
5. Make sure you have enabled `ExecCGI` for `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` directory in Apache configuration. For examples see at: http://opensuse.swerdna.org/suseapache.html. You can also use `ScriptAlias` directive.

Comment: Yes, my filename is file.cgi and the rights are read and write. The first line is #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: Does apache receive request with that file? Look at apache logs, especially `error.log` and `access.log` (probably in `/var/log/apache`)

Comment: Thank you so much! the error log really helped. It was not able to trace the file path. I changed the default cgi directory to /var/www/cgi-bin and put the script there. The file is being executed now. But now it shows an error "/usr/bin/env: python
: No such file or directory".

Comment: Check where you python interpreter is with `which python` command

Comment: which python gives "/usr/bin/python". In my cgi script, I have changed first line to #!/usr/bin/python and it still shows the same error

Comment: Try to run it from command line. Also make sure that this file uses Unix style of newlines (LF only instead of CRLF from DOS/Windows).

Comment: And how do I check i its UNIX style of newline?

Comment: Now its showing the error "(2)No such file or directory: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/file.cgi' failed". I think the error is there because this file is being considered as HTML/Plain text instead of script/python. How do I change the type to script/python?

Comment: Make sure you have enabled `ExecCGI` for `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` directory in Apache configuration. For examples see at: http://opensuse.swerdna.org/suseapache.html

Comment: http://infobees.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/python-cgi/ link describes all the steps required!